# Managing Application connections with couchbase secondary cluster, during complete failover of primary cluster

Tags: java, database-connection, couchbase, connection-pooling

I have cluster with cross datacenter replication enabled with two Datacenters. My application is running with Java code base.

Need some help on below things during complete failover of one Datacenter,

What are the best ways to redirect the traffic to secondary cluster, when primary is not available which restarting the application
Or the app stack restart is mandatory?
I'm not able to spot any relevant information in stackoverflow or CB forum . Kindly provide me the details if any answer is already exists,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Couchbase calls this feature Multi-Cluster Awareness (MCA). [Blog post](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-high-availability-disaster-recovery-java-multi-cluster-aware-client/). An updated MCA client for SDK 3 is in development.

Comment: This question is also being discussed on the Couchbase Forum. Cross-reference, for visitors from the future: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/managing-application-connections-with-couchbase-secondary-cluster-during-complete-failover-of-primary-cluster/29711